# iOS Bluetooth retrievePeripherals causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: ios, bluetooth, exc-bad-access, core-bluetooth

I need to periodically reconnect to a peripheral, but trying to re-connect crashes.

First, my central scans for peripherals' UUID, then it connects, then it stores the peripheral.UUID into a CFUUIDRef variable, and then disconnects.  Next, to re-connect it retrieves the UUID from variable, then either crashes with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when it does retreivePeripherals, or a little later when it does the subsequent didRetrievePeripherals.

Maybe I'm not storing the UUID correctly, but I don't see the bug.   Thanks.

Here's the code ..........

```
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    ///////////////////////   C E N T R A L   C O N N E C T E D   P E R I P H E R A L   //////////////////////

    [self.centralManager   stopScan];
    // Make sure we get the discovery callbacks
    peripheral.delegate = pwr_tx_management;

    switch( PWR_TX_manager.present_operation )
    {
        case POLLING_FOR_GENERIC_DVINEWAVE_DEVICE:
            if( dbg_ev )        printf("1");        
            // Add new record for connection device to local system status database:
            update_device_record( &packed_ad_record    );       //      ==>  device_record_index
            // Store peripheral UUID for later, perioed re-connection for polling:
            area_device_status[ device_area ][ device_record_index ].peripheral_UUID = peripheral.UUID;
                                 // uses declaration:  CFUUIDRef            peripheral_UUID;

    // Disconnect:        !!!
        [self.centralManager   cancelPeripheralConnection:   peripheral];
        break;


        case OPERATION_SPECIFIC_POLLING:
                                        NSLog( @"(7) didConnectPeripheral   " );
            if( dbg_ev )        printf("2");        
            // Proceed with reading device's status and updating local database:
                [peripheral   discoverServices:nil];    // request service, characteristics, then request device send its packed status record

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }    
}





// Connects to device specificed by index next_dbase_record .
void connect_specific_device( void )
{
                                                        NSLog( @"(5) connect_specific_device    - next_dbase_record = %d", next_dbase_record );
    CFUUIDRef uuid = area_device_status[ device_area ][ next_dbase_record ].peripheral_UUID;

    if( uuid )
    {
        // Request call to didRetrievePeripherals() with CBPeripheral:
        [pwr_tx_management.centralManager retrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject: (id)CFBridgingRelease(uuid)]];     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< crashes here with:  Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog( @"   - missing area_device_status[][].peripheral_UUID ");
    }

}



// Iniates connection to peripheral device specified before by retrievePeripherals.
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    NSLog( @"(6) didRetrievePeripherals");
    [central   connectPeripheral:peripheral   options:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to store the ASCII UUID, and use use retrieveConnectedPeripherals as well as retreivePeripherals.  Storing the pointer probably failed because the data was not retained.  I also implemented tdevoy's solution.  didRetrievePeripherals gets called but its peripherals list is empty, so I added to it retrieveConnectedPeripherals and didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals, which gets called, and lists the peripheral, which I successfully connect to.  (Apple Prog. guide for these is vague and lacks example code.)

Comment: So i don't really understand what you're saying. retrieveConnectedPeriphs only grabs the periphs you're already connected to. Is that what you were wanting to do?

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface this by saying I'm writing this from my cell phone in a car, so excuse me for the poor formatting. Ill just point out the main problem I see. You're not adopting the right delegate method:

It is:

```
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *) peripherals
```

Not this:

```
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
```

Also I don't see why you're doing that `cfbridgingrelease`. Just pass it in as `@[(id)yourCfuuidref]`. You didn't create that cfuuid.

Comment: I copied didRetrievePeripherals:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral from Apples temp_sensor example.  However, Apple's Health Thermometer and Heart Rate Monitor use the NSArray format.

Comment: I'm thinking the problem is in how I store the UUID.  I'm concerned that I'm storing a pointer, that somehow changes, and should be storing the ASCII UUID.

Comment: What you want to do is this: Store the NSString version of your UUID into NSUserDefaults. When you need it again, retrieve the UUID string and use CFUUIDCreateFromString to create your CFUUIDRef. Then pass that CFUUIDRef into retrievePeripherals